# Sorting list in c# based on some conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sort entries in a given list on Entry column in most efficient way. Below is the example how my i entries looks like.

```
#No Detail                                 Entry          Number          Rate
1   Carpool at 5$                          C              1               5
    Carpool at 5$                          H              2               5

2   Played Cricket at 2$                   X              1               2
    Played Cricket at 2$                   O              2               2

3   Done something at 4$                  ""              0               4

4   Done something else at 9$              M              1               9

5   Watched movie at 6$                    B              1               6
    Watched movie at 6$                    Z              2               6
```

**Some explanation about data:**

1. No column is not available in list. I just mentioned here to give detail about entries.
2. 1,2,5 are special clubbed entries and should be sorted together on Entry which have number column set to 1. These entries have
   specialty    that their rate and description would be same and
   Number would be 1    and 2.
3. There is possibility that there could be some entries which have
   empty Entry values, such entries will have number set to 0. Such as 3
4. There is possibility that there could be some entries which have
   single Entry value and will not have an pair and Number column for
   such entries would be set to 1 and there wouldn't be any entry in
   list which have same description and rate with Number column set to 2. Such as #4.
5. While sorting clubbed entries on Entry column only consider Entry
   with Number set to 1 and other entry should tag along.

I want to sort Entry column by ascending or descending order abiding above rules.

**My Solution:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Data
    {
        public string Detail { get; set; }
        public string Entry { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int Rate { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Data> entries = new List<Data>();

            // Clubbed entry...While sorting only consider entry with Number set to 1. They will have same rate and Detail.
            entries.Add(new Data() { Detail = "Carpool at 5$", Entry = "C", Number = 1, Rate = 5 });
            entries.Add(new Data() { Detail = "Carpool at 5$", Entry = "H", Number = 2, Rate = 5 });

            // Clubbed entry
            entries.Add(new Data() { Detail = "Played Cricket at 2$", Entry = "X", Number = 1, Rate = 2 });
            entries.Add(new Data() { Detail = "Played Cricket at 2$", Entry = "O", Number = 2, Rate = 2 });

            // entry which have empty Entry value such entries will have Number set to 0
            entries.Add(new Data() { Detail = "Done something at 4$", Entry = "", Number = 0, Rate = 4 });

            // entry which will not have an pair and Number column for such entries would be set to 1 and 
            // there wouldn't be any entry in list which have same detail and rate with Number coloumn set to 2
            entries.Add(new Data() { Detail = "Done something else at 9$", Entry = "M", Number = 1, Rate = 9 });

            // Clubbed entry
            entries.Add(new Data() { Detail = "Watched movie at 6$", Entry = "B", Number = 1, Rate = 6 });
            entries.Add(new Data() { Detail = "Watched movie at 6$", Entry = "Z", Number = 2, Rate = 6 });

            // Sorting on Entry Coloumn
            var sortedList = entries.GroupBy(x => x.Detail).OrderBy(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Number <= 1).Entry).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Detail                                 Entry          Number          Rate  
Done something at 4$                  ""              0               4

Watched movie at 6$                    B              1               6
Watched movie at 6$                    Z              2               6

Carpool at 5$                          C              1               5
Carpool at 5$                          H              2               5

Done something else at 9$              M              1               9

Played Cricket at 2$                   X              1               2
Played Cricket at 2$                   O              2               2
```

**Question:**

- My solution do not consider Rate and only groups based on Detail, can
  it be modified?

  - Can it be done using IComparer as in rest of my code had sorting done using IComparer?

Comment: IMO forget about speed. You have a handful of entries. This will run in a fraction of a milisecond pretty much whatever you do.. You're just prematurely optimising here.

Comment: You can take a look at an [IComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). This is the standard way to centralize sorting rules. You can then name the sort by purpose and change the compared properties centrally at will

Comment: @farlee2121 In-fact IComparer would be the best solution  for me as in existing code all the Column  sorting is done through IComparer but i couldn't figure out how to do grouping in Compare method. Can you tell me how do solve above problem above problem using IComparer

Comment: an ICompareer isn't going to be any more efficient that what you already have (presuming by efficiency you mean speed). It'll possibly do the same in a more succient way but it won't be any "faster". Your code is currently `O^n` complex. The addition of a dictionary would make it `O^n log n` complex but adding the data into the dictionary may negate any performance improvements. If you want true efficiency you need to measure your whole code, identify bottle necks and improve these. Tinkering with this is likely a waste of time.

Comment: @Liam  In my existing code all the column sorting is performed using IComparer and there is switch case inside compare method which take cares which column sorting need to be done, i went to Linq because i wasn't able to do it using IComparer. I wasn't able to group the entries using IComparer, It would be great if you can show me.

Comment: @Liam I would really appreciate if you can show me, how it can be done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181090/discussion-between-a-learn-and-liam).

Comment: I think this is question with enough information and partially working solution(believe me i have tried), if i knew the answer of question which i have asked then i wouldn't have asked the question in first place.

Comment: Standard LINQ group by is for grouping by consistent values. You can easily group by Detail and Rate using anonymous objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by Rate and Detail by creating an anonymous object. If you are using `FirstOrDefault` you should handle the possibility of a `null` return with `?.`. If you are not supposed to have a group that doesn't contain a `Number` of 0 or 1, you should just use `First`. You should sort the members of the group based on `Number`:

```
var sortedList = entries.GroupBy(x => new { x.Detail, x.Rate })
                        .OrderBy(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Number <= 1)?.Entry)
                        .SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(z => z.Number))
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: "OrderBy(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Number <= 1)?.Entry)" Will sort the group based on Entry which have Number set to 1 or less than 1. Then why SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(z => z.Number)) is needed wouldn't SelectMany(x => x) will work just like i did.

Comment: Let's say you want to `OrderByDescending` `Entry` instead - do you expect the grouped lines to still be in 1,2 order or 2,1 order? That is why you need the extra sub-sort. Alternatively, what if the original source order is random - you could end up with 2,1 even with ascending sort.